# ionic - help to install pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and have started developing into it. But I am having an issue while installing a pdf viewer to view pdfs. I am using a plugin DocumentViewer and importing it into components and modules.

```
import { DocumentViewer} from '@ionic-native/document-viewer'

export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(public document: DocumentViewer, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

My Page:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{item.text}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome User</h2>
  <p>
    Great job!

  </p>
</ion-content>
```

But simply it would not work, I tried some other plugins but with my limited knowledge about ionic, I don't get anywhere. I would appreciate you giving some help and even though you would use a different plugin or point to a question or tutorial that might help.

Thanks :)